# In OLS, why does the error term equal $\mathbf{y} - \hat{\mathbf{y}}$?

Tags: regression, least-squares, linear-model

In OLS, why does the error term equal $\mathbf{y} - \hat{\mathbf{y}}$? I would have assumed that

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{y} - \hat{\mathbf{y}} &= \mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta} + \boldsymbol{\varepsilon} - \mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}
\\
 &= \mathbf{X}(\boldsymbol{\beta} - \boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}) + \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}
\end{aligned}
$$

The only thing I can think of is that we assume $\boldsymbol{\beta} = \hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$, and that all the error is captured by $\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}$. I can't find this assumption in a textbook, though.

Comment: What your derivation shows is that *if* your estimator $\hat\beta$ were to be exactly equal to the true parameter $\beta$ (whether that is the case is unknown in practice as we do statistics precisely because we do not know $\beta$), then residuals $\hat\epsilon$ and errors $\epsilon$ would be identical.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The residual (you don’t mean “error”) is by how much your estimate misses the observed value.

You observe $y$.

You estimate $\hat y$.

You missed by $y-\hat y$.

The “error” term is unobserved but estimated by the residuals.

Comment: I see. So $\hat{\varepsilon}$ is the _residual_, which is an estimate of the error $\varepsilon$. We simply define it to be $y - \hat{y}$? I was a little surprised, because I expected us to disambiguate between the error in the estimate of $\beta$ and the unavoidable error implicit in $\varepsilon$. But $\hat{\varepsilon}$ captures both.